# Auto Generate edit, index, new, _form, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is an easy question but I can't remember how you auto generate the views _form, edit, index, new, etc.. in Rails. I thought that when you generated a controller and model it would auto create these items but it isn't. I know this can be done using scaffold but I didn't think it was required. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must use scaffolding for this, for example:

`ruby
 rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text`

This would create model, controller and views.

Comment: So when you run: "rails generate controller" then "rails generate model field1:string field2:string" it doesn't create the forms for you? I know this is redundant just want to make sure. Thanks for the quick reply!